# Variable Scoping in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, scope

Hi it might sound a simple task but i am a bit confused here

I have an event :

```
private void ManReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 int store = data[0];
}
```

and then another event function like :

```
private void measurementsRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

I would like to use the variable "store" in the second function. How can I ?

The form is declared as follows :

```
namespace myRfid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        }
}
```

Comment: Are the events in the same class?

Comment: Yes they are events in the same form

Comment: Ah ok.  Then what Pavel has posted below should help you  :)  Otherwise you'd need something a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put variable onto the class level

```
class ...
{
    private int store;

    private void ManReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        store = data[0];
    }

    private void measurementsRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use store
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it as shown in below code in your class but private as it would be used within class only as shown below :-

```
private int store;

private void ManReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.store = data[0];
}

private void measurementsRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.store//// however you want to use
}
```